Two columns with changes to a single column
I would like to have a document that uses two columns.  But in some instances, e.g. for diagrams, and particular part involving equations, I turn to single column.  Then continue with two columns.  How does one proceed doing such things neatly?

diagrams can use figure* for a spanning float, otherwise if you want \onecolumn for a section using larger equations then \twocolumn to go back (the latter two commands always start a new page) or see the multicolumn package

Switching between \onecolumn and \twocolumn does start a new page. It would be practical that even without multicol, latex could avoid the new page behaviour.

If you need to switch mid page you need multicol. latex providing this feature without needing to load a package would simply mean that multicol was preloaded in the format, which is possible (just as inputenc or xparse packages have been incorporated in recent years) but it's not currently planned and wouldn't really have any advantages

Then, really, \onecolumn and \twocolumn are mostly intended for sub-documents to be either one column or two columns. But not a mix of both.

they are what they are and are useful eg for a one column appendix in a two column paper, or a two column index in a one column paper, etc. But for your use case figure* is normally what you want, and comments on a question don't make a good forum for discussing a design of latex feature  that has been unchanged for 40 years and isn't likely to change soon.

At least there are some reasons to change to a new page.
